# Fermat's little theorem as a consequence of $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$ in $\Bbb Z_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Exercise in a book I am currently reading asks that I prove Fermat's little theorem as a consequence of the fact that in $\Bbb Z_p$ for any $x$ and $y$, $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$. Although this feels like it should be something very simple, the solution escapes me.

**Edit**: rephrased the question to avoid ambiguity

Comment: That is apparently true.

Comment: Even so, do you mind spelling it out? For some reason this has me stumped.

Comment: I meant that it was apparently true that the solution escaped you. If you had actually included a question, I might have tried to answer it.

Comment: @JohnHughes I have rephrased the question to make it more understandable

Comment: Hint for the future: generally try to include a question-mark somewhere, so that we know where the question is. More broadly, try to make it easier for those answering your question to do what they're doing on your behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to see it : this result implies that the set of $x$ such that $x^p=x$ is actually a subfield of any characteristic $p$ field $K$.

Taking $K=\mathbb{Z/pZ}$, we see that it doesn't have many subfields...

Comment: Oh, this makes it suddenly very simple. Elements for which $x^p=x$ is true form a subfield and $Z/pZ$ has no proper subfields (because every element is a generator for the whole field), therefore this is true for all elements of the field. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use induction to show that $x^p = x$.  For the inductive step, show that $x^p = x$ implies that $(x+1)^p = (x+1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm feeling very stupid today. Induction on what exactly, elements of the field, i.e. $1^p=1$, suppose it's true for $x$ and show it's true for $x+1$? And that would include every element, making the theorem true, is that it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I sort of prefer the one given by @Max below, as it's a bit more "algebra-minded"

Comment: That’s exactly it

Comment: Ok, now that I see it it's trivial, but as I said I kind of prefer the other answer, so I chose his as the accepted solution. Thank you very much for your help regardless!